# how to generate constructors from superclass programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, code-generation

I need to extend a rather simple existing code generator that generates a subclass to an existing class. Until now the base class was basically always the same well known class and the superclass based constructors were added through some fixed code.
A new use case involves inheriting from arbitrary classes where the superclass constructor signatures are not known in advance.
Eclipse has a great feature that does exactly what I need via a menu
command.
(Menu > Source > generate constructors from superclass...)
Is there any way I could just evoke that command programmatically (or rather create a tool based on that functionality that does the same in the given context)?
The Project I am working on is OSGI based. So I would expect it should be possible. What I basically need as a starting point is the Name of the OSGI package the includes the functionality and a link to the source code.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class  that does the add is

```java
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.codemanipulation.AddUnimplementedConstructorsOperation
```

This is heavily based on the Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree code.

Also note that this is an **internal** class so it is not part of the official API and should not be used directly.